# Discord Bot in JS not reading reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am currently developing a Discord bot and I am trying to add a kind of menu as the bot is supposed to be a guide for a game.
To make that work I am trying to add bot messages after reacting to the prior message.
I am testing it on a test message and the bot is supposed to send `Test1` if a user reacts with

After reacting, the bot simply does nothing. It doesn't crash nor does it send the intended message.

My code:

```js
case 'Testembed': //Testembed mit Reactions
    message.channel.send({embeds: [Testembed.de.data]}).then((question) => {
        question.react('')
        question.react('')
      
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['',''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
        };
        const collector = question.createReactionCollector(filter, { //<-- Here it stops working
            max: 1,
            time: 15000
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason === 'time') {
                message.channel.send('Ran out of time...');
            } else {
                let userReaction = collected.array()[0];
                let emoji = userReaction._emoji.name;

                if (emoji === ''){
                    message.channel.send('Test1');
                } else if (emoji === '') {
                    message.channel.send('Test2');
                } else {
                    message.channel.send("I don't understand ${emoji}...");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    break;
```

Edit: Bot now throws new error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: collected.array is not a function
```

Comment: Have you enabled / included the [`GuildMessageReactions`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits) intent on your client as well?

Comment: I think the problem is "emoji === ''" -> maybe you have to escape the emoji to unicode code?  like "emoji === '\ud83d\udc4d'"

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: @Caladan I got 14.2.0 installed.

Comment: @node_modules & Margon
I did not have the intent enabled, but I do now. Neither option worked though

Comment: @ColdRogue26 Which intents do you you have enabled? Could you add these in the post as well? What happens with other events, do you receive these as well?

Comment: @node_modules Got the following Intents now:
GuildMessages
Guilds
MessageContent
GuildMessageReactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `discord.js@14.x.x`, the method to create a reaction collector changed. Now, the collector would only take one argument and the filter variable would have to be passed in the object. An example would look like this:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['',''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
};
const collector = question.createReactionCollector({ 
    max: 1,
    time: 15000,
    filter
});
```

Comment: This worked in making my Bot read the reactions, now it throws the next error - Will try around to fix it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show it in your question?

Comment: Done. Hope I did it correct, still new to this

Comment: You got that error because the `collected` variable doesn't have an `.array()` method. Since you just want to access the first value in the `Collection`, you can just use `collected.first()`

Comment: This worked and the bot replies as intended now. Many thanks!